# VMWare ESXi 5 - Backup configuration

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have an `ESXi 5` which I will format the OS. Since I have a lot of configuration on it I want to backup the configuration.
**VMWare** suggest [this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2042141) method.
Anyone can confirm that this will work?

Comment: Why not pull the ESXi install drive / SD Card / USB key for safety's sake and restore to a replacement drive?  Then if any issues you can just swap the drive/key/card back.

Comment: Because is a RAID of hard disks. I cant afford to buy new disks and create a new RAID

Answer (score 0):

That method should work, mostly the esxi host's are static once they are configured with an ip, interfaces, and management. If you are talking about backing up the configuration of VCenter then you can just export the database that it uses to run. Vcenter is where all of the vlans, host configurations are mostly stored.